# Improving ArcPy script for ArcMap to only return rows of selected polygons instead of all polygons in layer

Tags: arcpy, cursor, arcgis-10.6, code-review

I am debugging a code provided to me that merges two polygons and alters the fields of "FID1' and "CALC_AREA."

I have realized that the current code searches every layer in the map document for fields containing "FID1" & "CALC_AREA", sorts them ascendingly, chooses the ID matching the largest "CALC_AREA" selected, and assigns the value to all IDs of merged polygons.

```
def populateMergeID():

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):

    # Describe cursor object for selected polygons sorted by area
    search = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyr, fields="FID1; CALC_AREA", sort_fields="CALC_AREA A")
    FID1 = ""
    area = 0


    for row in search:
        print "Current FID1!: "
        print row.FID1 
    # Just want the first row FID1 value
        if row.CALC_AREA > area:
            area = row.CALC_AREA
            FID1 = row.FID1
# Corresponds to largest polygon in selection
    print "The container polygon has FID1 value!!: " + FID1

    del search

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr,"mergeid") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = FID1
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            print row
    # del cursor
```

My question is that how would I write the script so that the search only looks for selected polygons instead of every polygon in the the map document.

Comment: First off, use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` -- The DA functions are *much* better than the effectively deprecated old-style cursors. Then you can rewrite the script to use the selection environment to alter selected rows (which are used by default in cursor operations). It's unclear what your actual goal is, but you might be able to use a single Update loop with a Select then a sorted Search.

Comment: Thanks! I've included the DA function and it works great, now I'm working on getting my sort function to behave.

Answer (score 1):

The arcpy search cursor has an optional SQL query that should be used to limit the rows returned instead of selecting by attribute. To my knowledge the arcpy search cursors will not honor existing selections. So if no SQL query is provided to the search cursor parameter you are searching through the entire table. The documentation can be found [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/searchcursor.htm).

[image]

So your code for example could look something like this:

```
search = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyr, where_clause='CALC_AREA > 250', fields="FID1; CALC_AREA", sort_fields="CALC_AREA A")
```

Lastly, in your instance the only reason to continue using the `arcpy.SearchCursor` vs. the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` is for the sorting capabilities, otherwise as stated in the ESRI documentation:

> The arcpy.da cursors (arcpy.da.SearchCursor, arcpy.da.UpdateCursor,
>   and arcpy.da.InsertCursor) were introduced with ArcGIS 10.1 to provide
>   significantly faster performance over the previously existing set of
>   cursor functions (arcpy.SearchCursor, arcpy.UpdateCursor, and
>   arcpy.InsertCursor). The original cursors are provided only for
>   continuing backward compatibility.

Comment: I agree, I have since changed my code to use arcpy.da.SearchCursor however I now having trouble once more with the cursor attempting to sort all parcels in the map document instead of only the parcels I selected. Here's the code I'm working with now
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("WEBBCAD_PARCELmerge")
`fields = ["FID1", "CALC_AREA"]
    lt = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            lt.append(row)`
Is this an instance where I still need a where_clause?